# Plot a function in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have to plot this function :

[image: Function]

where

[image: k2]

But I don't know how to do that!

I am supposed to use these libraries:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I need to plot:

- the function T(E) where E > U
- over the domain  where E is between (10 - 20)*10^-19

I am given that these constants:

- U is 9*10^-19
- h=1.34*10^-34
- m=1.6*10^-19
- a=2*10^-9

Can you help me set up the code to solve this problem?

Comment: I mean you've given equations, not functions. You haven't said what are independent variables and what are constants. Does `T = T(a)` or `T = T(U)`? What about `k2`. Does it vary with `m`? Is it constant? You haven't given us enough information to go on.

Comment: OK E > U, we can define free if we say E is between 10 to 20 and U is between 1to 9, h is planck constant, m is mass of an electron I will write these

Comment: T(E) I will plot

Comment: Surely you mean `T(E, U)`. `U` is also independent

Comment: Tried with this but that does not work:from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show
import math
a=2*10**-9
m=1.6*10**-19
h=1.8*10**-68
E=arange(10*10**-19, 20*10**-19,0.1)
U=9*10**-19
k=sqrt(2*m*(E-U)/h)
c=(U**2)*(sin(0.5*k*a))/(4*E*(E-U))
T=1/(1+c)
plot(T,E)

Comment: Don't put that much code in the comments, update your question and use code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is what you want to do

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # for 3d plotting

# constants
h = 1.34e-34
m = 1.6e-19
a = 2e-9

# define our function (python standard uses lowercase for funcs/vars)
def t(e, u):
    k2 = np.sqrt(2 * m * (e - u) / h**2)
    return 1 / (1 + ((u**2 * np.sin(k2 * a / 2)**2) / (4 * e * (e - u))))

# this is just a general function I use which quickly creates values needed 
# in 3D plotting
def grid(xs, ys, func):
    """
    Returns a tuple of (x, y, func(x, y)) points for use in 3d plotting
    using vectorized arithmetic for speed
    """
    if xs.ndim != ys.ndim != 1:
        raise ValueError(f'xs and ys must have 1 dimension, '
                         f'not xs.dim={xs.ndim}, ys.ndim={ys.ndim}')
    x, y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)
    z = func(x, y)
    return x, y, z

# create arrays in of the right range with some sensible discretisation
array_size = 100
es = np.linspace(10, 20, array_size)
us = np.linspace(1, 9, array_size)
x, y, z = grid(es, us, t)

# create the 3d plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.set_xlabel('E')
ax.set_ylabel('U')
ax.set_zlabel('T')

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

The output looks like this:

[image: 3d plot]

### Edit:

With new requirements `E in (10 - 20)*10^-19` and `U = 9*10^-19`

Using the same `t(e, u)` as before:

```
es = np.linspace(10e-19, 20e-19, array_size)
u = 9e-19
z = t(es, u)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlabel('E')
ax.set_ylabel('T(E)')

ax.plot(es, z)
plt.show()
```

outputs:

[image: 2d plot]

Comment: Thank you very much! but if we take U constant say 9e-9; how should the 2d plot be ? I mean T(E)?